# Film DCI4k or UHD for exporting DCI-Scope but watching on UHD screen

Tags: playback

Most of my films are 21:9 in DCI-Scope:

4096x1716p

I can record inside my camera with UHD or DCI 4k, and I'm not sure what is better for playback quality?

Shooting in UHD and cropping to about 3840x1608 so that on a UHD screen, each pixel can be mapped to one real pixel.

Or shooting DCI4k and cropping it to DCI4k Scope. Which means there isn't one pixel for each real pixel on the screen.

Or to better ask:
Does it improve quality when the screen has the exact same resolution as the video?

Answer (score 1):

I researched a bit more on my own and it looks like there is a diffrence but no big one.

While a native image will look better, the image quality isn't much diffrent when "downscaling" to UHD.

It might be noticable on a high quality projector screen, but on desktop and espacially on mobile screens it shouldn't be a problem.